On $A \otimes_k M_n(k)$ for a field $k$ and a $k$-algebra A

Hi, I am reading about taking the tensor product of a matrix algebra over $k$ with a $k$-module $A$ that might not be commutative. In the example in the image, I think the author is implying that $A \subset Z(A \otimes_k M_n(k))$, but I am not sure why this is the case. My understanding is that (e.g. see here Tensor product of $k$-algebras, center, isomorphism.)
$$
  Z(A \otimes_k M_n(k)) = Z(A) \otimes_k Z(M_n(k)) \cong Z(A) \otimes_k k = Z(A)
$$
where $Z(M_n(k))$ equals the set of matrices of the form $xI_n$ for $x \in k$, and is hence isomorphic to $k$. I don't see why that $A \subset Z(A)$, which is what the image seems to be getting at.
Alternatively, I would appreciate a more detailed proof of why $A \otimes_k M_n(k) \cong M_n(A)$

Maybe A is commutative?

For your second proof, just consider that
$\begin{align*}
M_n(A) &= \bigoplus_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant n} A \cdot E_{i,j} = \bigoplus_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant n} A \otimes_k k\cdot E_{i,j} = A \otimes_k \left(\bigoplus_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant n} k \cdot E_{i,j}\right)\\
& = A \otimes_k M_n(k)
\end{align*}$
Now I agree with the fact that the argument provided by the author works if he only works with commutative algebræ.
A more detailed proof lies here $M_n(k)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(B)$, where $k$ is a field, and $B$ is a $k$-algebra.
